# identify a word on a gas cylinder

Tags: перевод

can anyone tell what word is on the tank on the picture?
its on an old Soviet gas cylinder, probably has to do with welding or cutting

[image]

Comment: this question won't be valuable for a broader audience, so I'm voting to close it

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to tell based on what is left from the letters, but possibly [this article](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B8_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81_%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) may be of help - it is a standard of marking gas tanks based on the type of gas inside. Though it is marked as 2003 document, but it actually the same as the one approved in 1970.

Looks like this is a yellow text on black background, so it could be:

- Азот
- Углекислота
- 'Other non-flammable gas' (e.g. Неон)

Of these three the УГЛЕКИСЛОТА (CO2) is long enough, but I'm not sure if it is really it. If it is so, then we likely see the ЛЕКИС part of УГЛЕКИСЛОТА.

Углекислота (Carbon Dioxide) is used in welding to protect hot metal from contact with oxygen.

Below is a picture of CO2 tanks with hand-made УГЛЕКИСЛОТА inscription.

[image: CO2 tank]

Comment: Could easily be АЦЕТИЛЕН (acetylene gas for welding), ОГНЕОПАСНО (fire hazard) or НЕ КАНТОВАТЬ (do not flip).

Comment: According to the link Ацетилен is written red on white, other flammables like ПРОПАН are white on red (and ОГНЕОПАСНО is also written white on red). I don't think НЕ КАНТОВАТЬ is ever written on such tanks.

Comment: I'm sure an "old Soviet gas cylinder" of unknown provenance is guaranteed to follow marking standards established in 2003.

Comment: Here's the USSR document approved in 1970 with the same marking standards: http://www.alppp.ru/law/hozjajstvennaja-dejatelnost/promyshlennost/26/pravila-ustrojstva-i-bezopasnoj-ekspluatacii-sosudov-rabotayuschih-pod-davleniem.html

Comment: And here's the document about using CO2 in welding: http://www.tweld.ru/primenenie-uglekisloti-pri-svarke.html

Comment: @mustaccio a letter K is definitely visible here.